# Cubic root is not working

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, unicode-math

For this command

```
\[ \sqrt[\leftroot{-1}\uproot{2}\scriptstyle 3]{\frac{a}{b}} \]
```

or this

```
\[ \sqrt[3]{\frac{a}{b}} \]
```

the cubic root is not showing in shape:

The output in both cases:

[image]

How to get the actual cubic root symbol. Maybe it's conflicting with other packages. But I code not find it. No error is shown.

Note: I am using these packages.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\newcount\tmpcount
% re-do range No idea why this is needed
\AtBeginDocument{
\tmpcount="0980
\loop
\Umathcode\tmpcount 0 4 \tmpcount
\ifnum\tmpcount<"09FF
\advance\tmpcount 1
\repeat
}

\usepackage[explicit,compact]{titlesec}

\usepackage{afterpage}

\setlength{\parindent}{0in}


\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{GreenYellow}{RGB}{255,127,0} 

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}



\usepackage{imakeidx}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}



\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning} % position of figure elements

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}

\usepackage{enumitem}
            

% math packages
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
% template for solved examples
\newcounter{examplenum}[section]
\newenvironment{example}[1]{%1=instruction
%begin the environment
\refstepcounter{examplenum}
\noindent\textbf{উদাহরণ} \theexamplenum\hspace{0.6ex}\textit{#1}
\vspace{0.5ex}
%body of environment (the equations)
}{%
%close the environment
\hfill\(\color{blue!60}\rule{0.6em}{0.6em}\vspace{2ex}\)
}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,matrix,shapes.geometric, tikzmark}

\usepackage{array} % for left and right aligned text

\usepackage{wrapfig,booktabs}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}

\usetikzlibrary{fit,positioning,hobby}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}


\newcommand{\arrowlefto}[2]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (base) {#1};
    \node (dir) [right=0.1cm of base] {$^#2$};
    \draw[->] (dir.north) .. controls ++(0,.25) and ++(0,.25) .. (base.north);
\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document} 
    \[ \sqrt[3]{\frac{a}{b}} \] 
\end{document}
```

Comment: your code is incomplete and much too large. Try to make a complete, small example that demonstrates your problem. `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
\[ \sqrt[3]{\frac{a}{b}} \]
\end{document}` works fine for me.

Comment: It works fine for me as well in a single example. But I have a large document that uses many packages. All of them are listed here, that's why it is long. Sorry. Some of them may conflict, I suppose.

Comment: quite probably. But as you didn't show a complete example nobody can test and the only one who can identify the conflict is you. Copy everything in a test folder and then start to remove packages until you find the problem.

Comment: I have added complete example, but it works here, not in my actual document.

Comment: start from a copy of your complete document, delete all the text except for one math expression with a cube root, check the problem appears. then delete every package that you can delete from the preamble, checking at each stage that the problem appears. Post the resulting test document.

Comment: Ok. It needs some time.